# Why was a HNQ deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, hot-questions

The question [coworker made unsolicited comments about appearance](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/169560/coworker-made-unsolicited-comments-about-appearance) has been deleted. The 404 page directs me, and others, to the [deleted question help center page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions). But that page doesn't seem very accurate here, the question had an answer with a score of at least 1. And I didn't see any comments saying "questions that are extremely off topic" yesterday, did I miss them or forget them?

Why was the post deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original post, for those interested.

> This question was not nearly specific enough to garner useful answers.
>
> It was, in this moderators opinion, specifically geared to get a rise
> out of this group (trolling), and maybe intentionally geared for the
> HNQ.
>
> And as a bonus, unfortunately, this was asked on the weekend so it
> gathered the necessary steam to make the HNQ, gathering even more
> negative attention.
>
> If one of the other moderators want to un-delete it, they can I won't
> object -- but this question meets my criteria of a made up or trolling
> question rather easily.

*And after further discussion* with some other folks, I have un-deleted it, but left it closed.  Let's see what happens to it now.

And currently the question at hand is **open**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120078/discussion-on-answer-by-mister-positive-why-was-a-hnq-deleted).

Answer (score 4):

I don't see this as beyond the realm of possibility, esp since COVID.  In my office, we went from jacket and tie to "casual", to people ignoring the dress code altogether.  So much so, that if someone comes in dressed half decent, we will be treated to "How'd the interview go" or something equally silly.

The question didn't seem to me to be trolling, and I'm fairly aware of what is, as in my misspent youth, I trolled with the best of them.

The only hint that this person may not be legit is the low rep, but we all gotta start somewhere.

I know if I wore anything resembling professional attire to work, I'd get a similar reaction.

Besides, lately this place has had about as much life as the dark side of the moon.

Comment: It is now just closed, so edit away, edit away.

Comment: Edit what?  The OP lists several courses of action and asks about appropriateness of them. Not suggesting a course of action is not something this specific question can be accused of.

Comment: @mxyzplk I am responding to the suggestion that I agree with after reflection that the question can be edited as suggested in the comments to my answer.

Comment: @MisterPositive Done.

Answer (score -1):

Why is it necessary for someone look at the edit history of an answer in order to understand why a question was *deleted*? IMO it's better to include the reasons in the post, so visitors and users alike have a better understanding as to why an answer that *apparently* offers no clarification was accepted.

The mod responsible for deleting the post should explain to the community why the question was considered unsuitable at the time.

For what it's worth, the question didn't appear to be trollish. In my opinion,  it typifies the *worst* of the "me too" climate which pervades the workplace in the USA and in parts of Western Europe. Was the question a parody of a sexual harassment episode? Perhaps. But the COC used to say that we must [assume good intentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335026/we-need-assume-good-intent-back-in-the-code-of-conduct/335028#335028). At the end of the day, there was
there was nothing snarky or overtly provocative in the text (not that I'm aware of) to suggest its closure and subsequent deletion was warranted.

Comment: @user119079 someone else shares the same observation, but it didn't look it made much of an impact with the moderator, so why should I post the same comment? https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/why-was-a-hnq-deleted#comment22167_6836.  IMO it's better to include it in an answer, so visitors  and users alike have a better understanding as to why the OP accepted an answer that apparently doesn't explain "why".